# What is types property on redux-action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Watching this code:

```
return {
    types: [UPDATE_PROGRAM, UPDATE_PROGRAM_SUCCESS, UPDATE_PROGRAM_FAIL],
    promise: (client) => client.put(`${API_URL}/programs/${id}/`, {
      data: tempData
    })
  };
```

What is this types property and what is the difference between type and types? How does reducer pass this? Does it acts as dispatching 3 action at once? What is promice property? Why in reducer result property of action appears?

Comment: an action creator just returns any object, right?

Comment: It's for use in a custom api middleware. It never gets to the reducer. You can see it in the [redux real world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world). Look at the actions, and how the api middleware consumes them.